# putting strings into linked list

Tags: c++, c, singly-linked-list

My wordcount function has some issues. If anyone can please help.
I am reading characters from input file, converting them into words. I add them to linked list
and using print statements checking that every word is going into linked list. When i call My printList
function in wordcount function it only prints the head. Apparently head->next is null

```
typedef struct wordNode{
    int data;
    char *word;
    struct wordNode *next;
}wordNode;

void wordCount(char *FileName); // function prototype
void printList(wordNode *head);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i,j;
    int count = argc-1; // the count basically tells the for loop how many times to runs i.e number of files
    pid_t childpid[count], wpid; // making a childpid array for forking more than one process
        int status=0; // for parent process to wait for child

        if(argc >= 1){
            for(j=1; j<argc; j++){
                    childpid[j] = fork();

                    if(childpid[j] == -1)
                        printf("The fork didn't go through for process %d\n", j);
                    else if(childpid[j] == 0){
                       // printf("got here\n");
                        wordCount(argv[j]);
                }

            }
        }

        else {
            printf("incorrect no. of argc\n"); }


        //here the following code makes parent to wait for all the child processes to terminate

        while((wpid = wait(&status)) > 0){

            if ((wpid == -1)){
                printf("Father didn't wait for child to term");
                break;
            }
        }

        printf("All %d files have been counted\n", count);
        return 0;

}


void wordCount(char *FileName){
    char prev;  // keep track of last word that was read
    char character;// to keep track of each character when reading input data
    int words=0; // keep count of words
    FILE* fp;
    char thisword[100];

    int k=0;

    wordNode *head;
    wordNode *current;
    head=NULL;

    current = NULL;

    fp=fopen(FileName,"r");
    prev='\0';

    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("unable to open the file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    else{

    while((character = fgetc(fp)) != EOF ){

        if(character == ' ' || character == '\t' || character=='\0' || character =='\n' ){
            printf("in here\n");

            words++; 
            thisword[k]='\0';
            printf("HERE THE WORD is %s\n", thisword);
            printf("\n");
            if (head==NULL){

                head = malloc(sizeof(wordNode));
                head->next = malloc(sizeof(wordNode));
                head->word = (char *)calloc(strlen(thisword) + 1, strlen(thisword));
                strcpy(head->word, thisword);

                printf("%s \n", head->word);
                current = head->next;
            }

            else{
                current = (wordNode*)malloc(sizeof(wordNode));
                current->word = (char *)calloc(strlen(thisword) + 1,  strlen(thisword));
                strcpy(current->word, thisword);
                current->next = NULL;
                printf("%s\n ", current->word);
                current = current->next;
            }

            k=0;
         }

         else {
            thisword[k++] = tolower(character);   
         }

    }
        printList(head);
        printf("Child process for %s: number of words is %d\n", FileName,words);
        exit(0);
        fclose(fp);
    }   

}



void printList(wordNode *head)
{
    while(head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s ", head->word);
        head = head->next;
    }
```

Comment: `char character;` --> `int character;`

Comment: Please specify C or C++. They are different languages with different rules. For example in C++, `typedef struct wordNode{ ... }wordNode;` is wasted time. `struct wordNode{ ... };` is sufficient and in C the cast in `current = (wordNode*)malloc(sizeof(wordNode));` is not required.
`

Comment: Looks more like C; I don't know if it's possible to just remove the C++ tag. If C++ is desired, then are you fine just using `std::list<T>`, or does this have to be self-made?

Comment: Consider separating the linked list logic from the rest. It is almost always easier to get the linked list figured out on its own. Once you have a functional linked list, THEN it's safe to write code that uses it. If you try to integrate the two, you often spend many times longer debugging. In general, do one thing. Prove it works correctly. Move on to doing the next thing.

Comment: Your bug: Nothing in `if (head==NULL)`'s `else` case links new `wordNode` to anything other nodes. `head` is left pointing to NULL and the rest of the nodes are leaked.

Comment: I recommend using `std::string` in your node for text.  The `char` arrays will get messy and may inject issues especially when copying or initializing the node.

Comment: BTW, any statements after `exit()` will not be executed, because your program has exited to the operating system.

Comment: I am using c language.

Comment: Please simplify your example. Try counting the words in a single file whose name is hardcoded into your code. (Don't parse command line arguments until you have the logic working.) Better yet, hardcode the text to process and don't open a file. Don't fork a new process. If that works, add back complications one at a time until the problem resurfaces. Then re-simplify, removing the unneeded complications and narrowing down the problem to a [mcve].

Comment: Do you want to insert every character you encounter or a string separated by spaces. Also do you want to insert them at the start of the list or end of the list?